# How to interrupt someone in a polite manner?

Tags: politeness, idiom-request

What is a polite way of interrupting someone? In other words, what is an appropriate sentence to use when someone is talking and you need to interrupt them to add a point or ask a question because you think if you wait until they are finished you would miss the point?

Comment: "Could I stop you for a moment? I was wondering about..."

Comment: You could say also say _"Excuse me, but before I forget..."_ @Maryam … _Politely_ is an adverb, and cannot modify the noun _manner._ Do you know what the _adjective_ form of _politely_ is?

Comment: Oh, nice pick up. hmm, should I say "polite manner" ?

Comment: I would say, sorry for the interruption {interrupting you}, but I have to say this that... :-)